# Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Int?.Type' Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am trying to pass a value from one view controller to another of type `Int`.

Here is how I am invoking my sugue:

```
if questionNumber + 1 == quizBrain.quiz.count{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToScore", sender: self)
        }
```

My `prepare` function is:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToScore" {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
    destinationVC.finalScore = quizBrain.getScore()
        }
    }
```

Here is my destination view class:

```
import UIKit

class ResultViewController: UIViewController {

    var finalScore =  Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

`quizBrain.getScore()` fetches a value of type `Int`. I am trying to pass this value and catch it in the other view in `var finalScore`.

The error I am getting is:

`Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Int?.Type'`

I am not sure what this particularly means, I am new to Swift and was unable to find something similar with a type `Int?.Type`. I am also running into a similar issue if I try passing a `String` in a different project.

Comment: Replace `=` with `:`. You are going to *declare* the type rather than *assigning* a default value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `var finalScore =  Int?` to `var finalScore:Int = 0` fixed it! Not sure if this is a Swift version issue, would be helpful if somebody could confirm why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

An optional in Swift is a type that can hold either a value or no value. Optionals are written by appending a ? to any type:

You should define an optional integer like:

```
var finalScore: Int? //now the value of finalScore can be nil or any integer value etc.
```

While using the option values, there are couple of ways:

```
if finalScore != nil {
    print(finalScore!)
}
```

or

```
guard let score = finalScore else {
    return
}

print(score)
```

or

```
print(finalScore ?? 0)
```

For more info, you can refer Apple Doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

Swift basics: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_399